# Image Button and Admob banner is not working in android

Tags: android, admob, imagebutton

I have added a navigation drawer, a ImageView, Image Button and Admob Banner 
But i dont know why my Image Button is not working and also Ad banner is not displayed

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mypc.hitarthapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DrawerLayout dl;
NavigationView nv;
ImageButton btn;
ImageView iv;
AdView av;
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-7900332792984616/4506141248");
    dl=findViewById(R.id.dv);
    nv=findViewById(R.id.nv);
    av=findViewById(R.id.ad);
    btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
    iv=findViewById(R.id.img);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"My 
msg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,TaskAct.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


    AdRequest ar=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    av.loadAd(ar);


     nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
     NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) 
    {
            item.setChecked(true);
            dl.closeDrawers();

            return true;
        }
    });

}
}
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="164dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:background="@drawable/wallet" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="247dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/startearn" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
   </android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/myheader"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"> 
  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7900332792984616/4506141248">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mypc.hitarthapp">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" 
/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub- 
   7900332792984616/4506141248"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-7900332792984616/4506141248" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TaskAct"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        ></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mypc.hitarthapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

Where i m wrong??
Any help will be appreciated
thanks in advance

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Can you add your gradle file with your implementations?

Comment: thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1):

Your ads work as they should, I didn't have to change anything. To make your `ImageButton` work. I suggest to move it below the `DrawerLayout` like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="164dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        />



    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/dv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="247dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/startearn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: The button still doesn't respond? Is your code here the latest you used?

Comment: but in my enulator it is not showing any add banner

Comment: Might be just an emulator problem. Can you test it on a real device? YOu shouldn't have any problem with it

Comment: What API does your emulator use?

Comment: yes ,the only change i have made is that i have placed AdView above the Drawer layout

Comment: Oh and give your `AdView` height and width `wrap_content`, not `10dp`. You might try it with google test id: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`

Comment: it have changed it

Comment: You need to be more precise: did you test in on a real device or on emulator? Do you still have the same problems than before?

Comment: no i didn't try on real device as ,usb options are not allowed in my device

Comment: Maybe you have just got emulator issues. Again: for me your code works after putting the image button below the `DrawerLayout`. If your device doesn't support the needed usb features, export the apk and load it on your device e.g. I think outside the emulator everything will work

Comment: okk tried placing sample id in place of my own id this ,works fine ,but when i put my own id it just shows white empty box .and the ImageButton is still not working

Comment: If it works I'd be happy if you accepted my answer. If there are problems left, please tell me about them!

Answer (score -2):

In your app.gradle, have you been putted the implementations??

In dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
```

After dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Activity with admob:

```
// AdMob
AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
//R.string.admob_app_id is a string resource with my app id]
```

If continues without work, you can try test just with the banner admob, and after puts your navigation drawer.

Comment: Try use the tools > firebase inside android studio, I made by there.